# My cat still hasn't adjusted to the new house after 2 weeks of living here

Tags: cats, behavior

My cat, Marty, is a real fraidy cat. He doesn't like most new people, but eventually he'll grow to like them.

We recently moved into my grandpa's house a city over from where we used to live. Currently, my cat is hiding under my bed. Usually at night, he'll come out from hiding and come downstairs when he knows it's just me, my sister, my brother and my mom downstairs, but sometimes when he's hungry he'll come out during the day, but only if one of us comes down the stairs with him. He's gotten pretty used to my uncle, he lets him pet him for a while, but he hasn't gotten used to my grandpa.

Also at night when we all go to bed he'll follow us upstairs, and he'll always sleep on my bed with me. He's not interested in sleeping on anyone elses bed, even if my sister picks him up and puts him on her bed, he usually just jumps right off and jumps onto my bed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: often cats take a month or even two to settle in in a new home.but your cat comes to you and your bed so just give him some time.

Answer (score 4):

Two weeks isn't all that long. Our first two cats were incredibly shy (they lived in the wild in a prison, where they had learned to stay quiet and out of sight).

It took them *months* to just be out in the open in the living room. We had kept them in a single room for the first two weeks. We then also gave them the hallway, and it took them over a week to actually want to go into the hallway. The same happened when we opened the door to the living room. And for two more months, they would never go downstairs without us, or during the day.

Your cat is by itself, getting to meet several new people, and also shy. I would give her a few extra weeks (if not months) before you see full integration into the household.

Answer (score 2):

If he has something he likes: toys, bed or even litter in another litter box, placing it out in the open where you want him to be could help him feel more comfortable. If your kitty likes treats you could encourage him by putting some treats where you want him to be. You could also try this with catnip instead of treats.

Answer (score 1):

Cats, unlike dogs, are teritorial creatures - they get used to the place. They do not take well when moving. Two weeks is normal, it may take months. I would suggest you do not force him. He will explore when and where he feels comfortable. As long as he eats and drinks water, uses his litter box he will be fine.

It is normal for him to become more active during the night, that is when they hunt and explore. Cat's are curious by nature. Hiding makes him feel safe, so let him be, and don't try to force him out.

Toys, treats, cat nip may motivate him but that depends a lot on the breed and character of the cat, it won't hurt to try. Just don't put his food, water and box at a place he cannot find it or doesn't want to go.